devtools won't show anything on nuxt version 3.14
I have a problem with my devtools on Google Chrome when I click on it I see the white window and it won't show anything like this:

after checking my console I can find this error:
Nuxt DevTools client injection failed

Updated: I Checked it on Safari and it works, and I think the problem is with Chrome
My Google Chrome version is 129.0.x
Any Idea how to fix it on Google Chrome?

Does it work in a private window?

no, it's not working

I was with the same issue, I just noticed that my nuxt/devtools was 1.4.1, I updated to v1.5.1 ( latest )


There is a javascript import bug in Chrome v129 that is potentially the issue if you are running this version. This also affects the current version of MS Edge since they use Chromium also under the hood.
Using Firefox or Safari is a decent workaround in the interim.

Discussion in the devtools repo
Confirmation from the Chrome team


I faced the same issue in Google Chrome, where the devtools displayed a white window. What worked for me was simply closing the window by pressed ctrl + shift + I and reopen by pressed ctrl + shift + I and go Vue devtool.
If it does not work by someone then follow @Jhony Souza answer. Moreover, below steps are helpful to troubleshoot,

Clear Chrome's cache to see if it's a cache-related issue.
Make sure the Chrome is fully updated to the latest version.


The 2 devtools are not really comparable in terms of power tho...
